# The most efficient way to query by range in Python

Tags: python, sorting

Given data like below:

```
Row_1 Alice_23
Row_2 David_32
Row_3 John_40
Row_4 Smith_28
```

Now if given age range(20, 30), both inclusive, I'd like to get `Row_1 Alice_23` and `Row_4 Smith_28`. I know in terms of algorithm, this is easy; but now I'm asking in Python what'll be the most efficient or optimal way to do this?

Note:
The data is just list on-fly, and not that big; let's assume at most tens of thousands of lines.

Comment: What data structure is the data stored in? Is this a file? A list? A database table?

Comment: Let's assume just a list on the fly, regardless where it's stored. And it's not big data, at most tens of thousands of lines.

Comment: "I know in terms of algorithm, this is easy". So what's this easy algorithm you know of? Python is just a programming language that helps implement this algorithm. Please update your question with the algorithm and your attempt in its implementation so we can help.

Comment: If you are looking for a Python data structure that supports lookup by range, you are out of luck. Your search is going to involve a full scan of the data no matter what. To eliminate repeated scans you can preprocess the data.

Answer (score 0):

For fast *queries*, maybe preprocess to then do this:

```
def rows(min_age, max_age):
    return age_sorted_rows[start[min_age] : stop[max_age]]
```

Where `age_sorted_rows` are your rows sorted by age, `start[age]` tells you the index in `age_sorted_rows` where that `age` starts and `stop[age]` tells you the index in `age_sorted_rows` where that `age` stops.

Demo with one possible implementation of the preprocessing:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

rows = '''Row_1 Alice_23
Row_2 David_32
Row_3 John_40
Row_4 Smith_28'''.splitlines()

def age(row):
    return int(row.split('_')[-1])
               
age_sorted_rows = sorted(rows, key=age)
start = [bisect_left(age_sorted_rows, a, key=age) for a in range(200)]
stop = [bisect_right(age_sorted_rows, a, key=age) for a in range(200)]

def rows(min_age, max_age):
    return age_sorted_rows[start[min_age] : stop[max_age]]

print(rows(20, 30))
```

Output:

```
['Row_1 Alice_23', 'Row_4 Smith_28']
```